# Codeigniter - empty post() but get()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have strange problem with codeigniter form.

So, I'm using form_open helper and it gives me this html code:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/controller/function" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

when I submit the form, I get an empty array but, when I put form without method only with HTML:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/controller/function">
```

I have my inputs in the array.

On the other hand, I've tried with GET instead of POST and I also have my inputs in the array.

My .htaccess:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /stillfresh
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Just to mention, my csrf_protection is set to FALSE, base_url is defined and $config['index_page'] = '';.

I'm wondering if the problem is caused by server or CI but I'm using this CI version for other project with no issues.

So my shorten code looks like:

```
    <?php 
    $form_data = array('name' => 'form_name');
    echo form_open('controller/function', $form_data);
    ?>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First name" autocomplete="off">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Can we see a more complete version of your form with inputs etc...

Comment: Updated with view

Comment: Thanks, can you show us the php code in `controller/function` that is checking the inputs

Comment: Just this:
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->input->post());
        echo '</pre>';

Comment: I'm kinda stumped now bro. Does `print_r($_POST);` give you anything?

Comment: Nothing, just array(), but with method="get", when I do print_r($this->input->get()), I have an array with input value: array(''first_name' => 'something');

Comment: I guess there is something with permissions or security on the server, hope someone else had the same problem

Comment: Now I'm sure it's something with server, I've checked on other server and it works normally, thanks mate anyway for the help

Comment: can you post the controller code you are using?

Comment: Maybe you are being redirected by apache2 somehow ? If that happens, post data are lost but not get. Try to use the network tab of your browser dev tools.